# How would I perform an action when a UITabBarItem is clicked in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I would like to update my UITableView when a Tab Bar Item is clicked. (I am open to any other better suggestions of how to do this besides when the Tab  Bar Item is clicked). Thanks for any help :)

[Tab Bar Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRDhT.png)

Comment: I tried to drag it over to the viewController but it only allows for an IBOutlet and Outlet Collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting the update code in the `viewDidAppear()` method

Answer (score 0):

Put your table view's update code in its view controller's `viewWillAppear()`, which should get called every time the tab is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this delegate

`optional func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
                     didSelect viewController: UIViewController)`

Comment: I tried using this method but it didn't work. I think it was because I didn't connect it to the actual button properly, how would I do that?